# Reading specific parts of text file

Tags: c#

I want to read all the lines written to a text file that is constantly being updated. I have tried the following method but this has led to me reading in duplicate files.

1. Get file size
2. Read frm zero to end of file
3. Start reading from filesize in step 1 to end of file
4. Repeat previous step

The problem with this is that I duplicate files that are written to the file while I am reading it. This is because I am reading to the end of the file.

What I would like to do is the following

1. Get file size
2. Read frm zero to file size from step 1
3. Get file size
4. Start reading from filesize in step 1 to file size from step 3
5. Repeat previous steps

This way I will never duplicate lines read.

Is this possible, I think I will need to specify a start point and end point for a stream reader/file reader to read a file.

Comment: if possible, don't use a volatile text file to communicate between processes.

Comment: Unfortunately the text file is not mine, I just have to read it and put the contents into a database. I want to avoid duplicating lines.

Answer (score 0):

If your really do have to use a file for inter process communication, you could investigate using a [Memory Mapped File.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267538.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to try something like this:

1. Rename the file to a temporary name
2. Create a new empty file with the original name
3. Process the temporary file
4. Repeat

If for some reason the file is always locked by the other process you could try this alteration of the same process.

1. Copy the file to a temporary name
2. Take note of the file size
3. Process the File
4. Repeat, starting processing from FileSize + 1 on the next pass